# Object following path not on the same axis

Tags: bezier-curves

I have an object which follows a Bezier curve, I've made enough segments so it can follow the curve. on the top samples, I've set the axis to X and the object follows the curve on the same Axis and same location axis, but the object doesn't seem as the Bezier shape spiral curve, its incomplete and just goes off direction and intersects with parts of the object.

On the bottom I set the axis on -X the object follows the curve perfectly making the spiral shape, but its not on the same level axis. If I try move it up or down, the whole object deforms. I've tried applying all transforms, but that didn't help. So what am I doing wrong so I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). It'll be one of those many many things that can go wrong with curve modifier (origin points, orientation, radius...). Would be best to share the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Jachym, here's the file. Its weird why its doing this so I'd like to know the theory behind it.:  https://pasteall.org/blend/63243eeb00334c859900304ef99635e7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" with curve modifier is, that you should have

- all scale/rotations applied
- your origins should be the same

so

1.) select your curve, press CTRL-A and apply scale

[image]

2.) change the y-value to 0

3.) select your cube -> press tab for edit mode, press A to select all

[image]

4.) now move the whole mesh so that is centers the origin point like this:

[image]

5.) press tab again

[image]

6.) now change the x-value as much as you need it

[image]